# Unix command to delete two folders at once?

Tags: unix

What is the Unix command to delete two folders at once? Using `rm -rf`?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes:

```
rm -rf /path/to/folder1 /other/folder/in/different/place
```

The '-f' is not mandatory if you can write to each file and directory, or if you don't mind being asked lots of questions.  The directories are deleted sequentially, but both are deleted as the result of a single command.

Comment: i don't know why i didn't just try this...

Answer (score 23):

In bash, there is a way to insert a list of arguments with curly braces:

```
rm -rf /path/to/{folder1,folder2}
will run
rm -rf /path/to/folder1 /path/to/folder2
```

It can be inserted anywhere:

```
rm -rf /{folder1,folder2}/subfolder
will run
rm -rf /folder1/subfolder /folder2/subfolder
```

Comment: Its called "shell expansion" if anyone wants to look it up.

Comment: so thats what its called! i tried to search it but couldnt even form a good search criteria.

Comment: The sub-section that describes expansion of material in braces `{…}` is [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion); it is the first step listed in the section on [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) in general because it occurs first.

Answer (score 7):

If you want the deletion to actually be concurrent, which can be faster if they are on separate disks, but probably slower if they are on the same one:

```
rm -rf /path/to/folder1 &
rm -rf /other/folder/in/different/place
```

Comment: good point, although I was looking more for a quicker (lazier) way to delete two folders